# Изменить качество видео с помощью php

Tags: php, видео

Нужно при загрузке видеофайла на сервер сохранять его в исходном и хуже качествах с расширением avi или mp4. 
Как это можно реализовать?

В гугле и яндексе я уже искал решения- ничего, кроме каких-то сторонних программ под windows не нашел.

К слову, нужно мне это для того, чтобы в плеере jplayer менять качество видео. Если кто-нибудь знает, как это можно делать не имея по видеофайлу на качество- пишите.

Comment: Например, можно использовать [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) через командную строку. Или найти какие-нибудь расширения для PHP, базирующиеся на нём.

Comment: ffmpeg есть на php, кроме него похоже ничего нет =)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но зачем писать ответ в виде комментария?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит ffmpeg. Благодарю. Только пишите пожалуйста ответы как это положено.